# how to turn from one expressions to another, different expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to go from this  expressions  $$3(x-2)^{5/3}-5(x-6)(x-2)^{2/5}$$ to something simpler 
I was trying to go with common factor but it didn't seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

The following might be simpler.

$$\begin{align}3\times (x-2)^{5/3}-5\times (x-6)(x-2)^{2/5}&=3(x-2)^{25/15}-5(x-6)(x-2)^{6/15}\\&=(x-2)^{6/15}\{3(x-2)^{19/15}-5(x-6)\}\\&=(x-2)^{2/5}\{3(x-2)(x-2)^{4/15}-5x+30\}\end{align}$$

Comment: @user7777777: Is this what you want? I suspect it cannot be much simpler.

Comment: it suppose to have two terms

Comment: Is the expression of your question exaclty what you want to consider?

Comment: I didn't think so

Comment: I mean, did you write the expression correctly?